# Remote management of Hyper-V server and its VMs

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-access

I am setting up a Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 server (SRV1) with several VMs. Some of those VMs will contain Active Directory, SQL Server, Apps, etc. I also have a second phyiscal server (SRV2) with AD as my backup domain controller.

I am almost never on-site, so in order to take advantage of RSAT tools I need to remotely log into a Windows box, running Windows 8.1 or higher (I don't have Windows on my personal computers). Unfortunately I don't have a dedicated PC at the site. In the past before virtualization, I remoted in directly to the server and performed my work.

Now, I'd like to remote in, but should I:

- Designate one of the VMs as a remote-in point (then I can't fully manage that VM like restarting since I'm connected to it)?
- Or should the backup DC be where I remote (hopefully not, because all it runs is AD and has low RAM).

I don't really like the idea of remoting in to the Hyper-V host itself. I do plan on implementing Remote Desktop Terminal Services Gateway. Any thoughts on a good setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Remote Desktop Gateway (hosted on a separated physical server) as a way to connect to all the VMs I needed. I had to set up the proper security certificates, and security access groups in AD, and configure the Remote Desktop Client to connect via the gateway. Not sure how it compares to other setups, but it has worked well for me these last two years.